# How to setup SSH/PuTTY to use Yubikey OpenPGP authentication?

Tags: ssh, putty, authentication, openpgp, yubikey

I would like to use YubiKey's OpenPGP interface to [authenticate](https://developers.yubico.com/PGP/SSH_authentication/Windows.html) myself against my OpenSSH server on Windows 10:

- I created the keys according to [this](https://developers.yubico.com/PGP/Importing_keys.html):

  ```
  gpg --card-status

    Reader ...........: Yubico Yubikey 4 OTP U2F CCID 0
    Application ID ...: BEEFBEEFBEEFBEEFBEEFBEEF99990000
    Version ..........: 2.1
    Manufacturer .....: Yubico
    Serial number ....: 99999999
    Name of cardholder: John Doe
    Language prefs ...: en
    Sex ..............: male
    URL of public key : https://example.com/pgp.asc
    Login data .......: johndoe
    Signature PIN ....: required
    Key attributes ...: rsa4096 rsa4096 rsa4096
    Max. PIN lengths .: 127 127 127
    PIN retry counter : 3 3 3
    Signature counter : 39
    Signature key ....: BEEF BEEF BEEF BEEF BEEF  BEEF BEEF BEEF BEEF 0001
          created ....: 2017-11-20 00:00:01
    Encryption key....: BEEF BEEF BEEF BEEF BEEF  BEEF BEEF BEEF BEEF 0002
          created ....: 2017-11-20 00:00:02
    Authentication key: BEEF BEEF BEEF BEEF BEEF  BEEF BEEF BEEF BEEF 0003
          created ....: 2017-11-20 00:00:03
    General key info..: pub  rsa4096/BEEFBEEFBEEF0001 2017-11-20 John Doe <john@example.com>
    sec>  rsa4096/BEEFBEEFBEEF0001  created: 2017-11-20  expires: never
                                    Cardnumber:BEEF BEEF9999
    ssb>  rsa4096/BEEFBEEFBEEF0002  created: 2017-11-20  expires: never
                                    Cardnumber:BEEF BEEF9999
    ssb>  rsa4096/BEEFBEEFBEEF0003  created: 2017-11-20  expires: never
                                    Cardnumber:BEEF BEEF9999
  ```
- PuTTY should work per the [documentation](https://developers.yubico.com/PGP/SSH_authentication/Windows.html), as I extracted the public key [below], reinserted the YubiKey, and restarted `gpg-agent`, however SSH login failed:

  ```
  gpg --export-ssh-key BEEF0003

    ssh-rsa [...] openpgp:0xBEEF0003
  ```

I found another [tutorial](https://occamy.chemistry.jhu.edu/references/pubsoft/YubikeySSH/index.php) on how to using YubiKey for SSH authentication, setting it up the way McQueen Labs [recommend](https://occamy.chemistry.jhu.edu/references/pubsoft/YubikeySSH/index.php), but this didn't work either:

- There wasn't a prompt for the card pin, making me think either this kind of SSH authentication is not done via PKE [unlikely] or there is a configuration option missing, as I received error:

  ```
  No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
  ```

How do I set up PuTTY to use YubiKey OpenPGP authentication and what do I configure on the server side?

Comment: I just realized I had Keepass with the KeeAgent plugin competing with gpg-agent for putty credential requests. I grew suspicious when the KeePass password window popped up after opening putty... . So double check and make sure you don't have any other pageant running in the background. Working fine for me after disabling the KeeAgent plugin.

Comment: No Keepass running on the machine. But thanks for the hint. And  with Pageant, I have tested both states.

Comment: I noted a difference in behaviour after adding the `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin` and `C:\Program Files\PuTTY` directories to the PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with my YubiKey 5 NFC and it seems PuTTY couldn't read the config or `pubring` files:

- Changing the home directory for `gpg` on Windows 10 solved the problem: 
  From: `%APPDATA%\gnupg\` To: `%HOMEPATH%\gnupg\`

  - Check the `gpg` home directory: `gpg --version`
  - Change the home directory: create environment variable `GNUPGHOME` within the new home directory

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial on using Yubikeys with PGP keys via SSH to log into Linux from Windows, hope it helps anyone as confused as I was: https://horugame.com/sign-in-to-linux-from-windows-via-yubikey/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill, not sure what to quote exactly as the entire tutorial is about how to set this up. PGP can get quite finicky, especially with a Yubikey involved.

Comment: I upvoted - because it's VERY long and complicated (and a great article) - and am not really sure how I'd summarize it for this format.